# Does paper have tooth levels?

Tags: paper

I was told in the other question that cold press paper means paper having tooth.

So, I want to know - are there any levels of tooth in papers?

I have paper in the house. It is not glazed. I want to know how much tooth it has.

Google search resulted in tooth decay information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! Different papers have different "tooth" -- this is another term for the *roughness* of the paper. The smoother a piece of paper feels, the less tooth; the rougher, the more tooth.

Most writing or copier/printer paper has very little tooth. It's not common for a tooth "value" to be shown on a package of paper, but different levels of tooth are sold for different purposes:

[image]
<sub>*Image from [Hello Artsy: How to choose quality drawing paper](http://helloartsy.com/how-to-choose-quality-drawing-paper/)*</sub>

Comment: What am I supposed to the tell the shopkeeper about the kind of paper that I want.  I live in India, I don't think shopkeepers would know about the teeth.

Comment: Try specifying what you want to draw with -- "a pad of drawing paper that is for graphite or colored pencils", for example. (It may also help to find that product on Amazon and bring them that description.)

Comment: The shopkeeper might understand "roughness" or "texture" if the term "tooth" doesn't translate well.

Answer (score 1):

From [DickBlick](https://www.dickblick.com/productinfo/learn/paper/#question2):

> Manufacturers generally offer three or more finishes, usually labeled rough, cold press, not/cold press and hot press.

I have never seen "not press" as a substitute for cold press, it might be regional. So in order of rough to smooth: rough, cold press, hot press. Bond is a hot pressed paper. Plate paper is the smoothest.

Of course your best bet is to look at/feel the paper yourself, but these catagories should give you a starting point.