# Do oil pastels work better on paper with more teeth?

Tags: paper, oil-pastels

Recently I have switched from soft pastels to oil pastels and I am curious if I should use papers with more teeth or a bit smoother or maybe average teeth.

Do oil pastels work better with paper that has more teeth?

Answer (score 8):

Oil pastels work well on paper with a fairly high tooth level. It helps it "grab" the color -- a "toothier" paper is better than a smoother paper.

I'll borrow this diagram I used [in a similar answer](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/656/30). You want pretty rough paper (but not quite the roughest), but somewhat smoother than you might have used for regular pastels.

[image]
<sub>*Image from [Hello Artsy: How to choose quality drawing paper](http://helloartsy.com/how-to-choose-quality-drawing-paper/)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Oil pastels work well on many surfaces, so I would suggest you try a variety of papers and other substrates and see which you like best.

A usefull site discussing this topic can be found [here](http://www.explore-oil-pastels-with-robert-sloan.com/papers.html).